# Android: hide keyboard and show it again after spinner is closed

Tags: android, keyboard, spinner, android-spinner

I have an activity with a Spinner and an EditText. If I focus the EditText, the keyboard is shown. Ok. If I then touch the Spinner, the keyboard should be hidden. I got this (see code).

Now my problem:
When I close the Spinner (no matter if an item is selected or not) it would be nice if the keyboard opens again for the EditText without clicking it. (when opening the Spinner the focus remains on the EditText)

```
EditText myET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
Spinner mySpin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

Spinner.OnTouchListener hideKeyboard = new Spinner.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        return false;
    }
};
mySpin.setOnTouchListener(hideKeyboard);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code in onItemSelected

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

this will open the keyboard for the next editText automatically.

Comment: this only works if I choose an item (not the same as the already selected item)

Comment: may be on the editText above the spinner you can check that when the user click on enter to go to next editText (which in this case must be closing the keyboard) you should check if the spinner item is selected, if its selected then you should use the code above to open keyboard for the next editText

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to show keyboard again on item selected:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                // open keyboard code here.
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

Note:  use click listener to fulfill your requirement. as direct click listener on spinner doesn't supported so make a class extend spinner and over ride on click method and in this method do what you want to do.

```
/** Spinner extension that calls onItemSelected even when the selection is the same as its previous value */
    public class CutomSpinner extends Spinner {

      public CutomSpinner(Context context)
      { super(context); }

      public CutomSpinner (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
      { super(context, attrs); }

      public CutomSpinner (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
      { super(context, attrs, defStyle); }

      @Override public void
      setSelection(int position, boolean animate)
      {
        boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
        super.setSelection(position, animate);
        if (sameSelected) {
          // Spinner does not call the OnItemSelectedListener if the same item is selected, so do it manually now
          getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());
        }
      }

      @Override public void
      setSelection(int position)
      {
        boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
        super.setSelection(position);
        if (sameSelected) {
          // Spinner does not call the OnItemSelectedListener if the same item is selected, so do it manually now
          getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: works only if I select a new item, not if I close the spinner with the same selection as before or without a selection

Comment: Have you tried adding the same code to onNothingSelected() ?

Comment: Yes I did. Seems as if this section is never reached

Comment: Could it be that a Spinner is something like a popup window or dropdown list or something like that that could use some other listeners?

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution that can do the following

when u press on edittext keyboard shows then when u press on spinner it disappears

then when u select item on spinner even if same item the keyboard appears again

final prob you have that what if i press on spinner (so keyboard disappears) then i press anywhere on screen ( i want keyboard to reappear ) that is easy just make global boolean set to true each time u make keyboard appears and vice versa and make onClickListener for all views in activity except for spinner ofcourse and that onClickListener has following code

```
boolean keyboardIsVisible; // which is true if keyboard is visible
if (!keyboardIsVisible) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

**here is the code** that solves all of that except final prob as i already told u how to solve it

**CustomSpinner.java**

```
public class CustomSpinner extends Spinner {

    Context mainContext;

    public CustomSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mainContext = context;
    }

    public CustomSpinner (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mainContext = context;
    }

    public CustomSpinner (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mainContext = context;
    }

    @Override public void
    setSelection(int position) {
        boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
        super.setSelection(position);
        if (sameSelected) {
            Activity activity = (Activity) mainContext;

            EditText editText = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                    activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;
    Button button;
    CustomSpinner customSpinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        customSpinner = (CustomSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        customSpinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                editText.setEnabled(false);
                editText.setEnabled(true);
                return false;
            }
        });

        customSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            int count = 0;

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (count > 0){
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                }else count++;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                // Do Nothing
            }
        });
    }

}
```